# In trouble with QFT field operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, fourier-transform

I'm stuck on the contents of a side box in "QFT for the Gifted Amateur", chapter 4, dealing about field operators. The side box sets the scene about the use case the section will be exploring, i.e. particle-in-a-box scenario.

Under the assumption of a box of volume $V$ and using periodic boundary conditions, it's easy to see that the normalization constant for the wave function in momentum coordinates is $1/\sqrt V$, rather than the usual $1/\sqrt {2\pi\hbar}$. Starting from this, the side box goes on as:

> A state $|\alpha\rangle$ can be described in position coordinates $\psi_\alpha(\boldsymbol{x})=\langle \boldsymbol{x}|\alpha \rangle$ or momentum coordinates $\psi_\alpha(\boldsymbol{p})=\langle \boldsymbol{p}|\alpha \rangle$, and since:
>
> $$\langle \boldsymbol{p}|\alpha \rangle = \int {d^3x \langle \boldsymbol{p}|\boldsymbol{x} \rangle \langle \boldsymbol{x}|\alpha \rangle}$$
>
> then the Fourier transform:
>
> $$\tilde \psi_\alpha(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac 1 {\sqrt V}\int {d^3xe^{-i\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}\psi_\alpha(\boldsymbol{x})}$$
>
> implies that
>
> $$\langle \boldsymbol{p}|\boldsymbol{x} \rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt V}e^{-i\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}$$
>
> The inverse transform is:
>
> $$\psi_\alpha(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac 1 {\sqrt V}\sum_{\boldsymbol{p}}e^{i\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}\tilde \psi_\alpha(\boldsymbol{p})$$
>
> since $\boldsymbol{p}$ takes discrete values.

So far so good (and apologies for the long quote, but I wanted to set the scenario properly). Now comes the bit I'm struggling about.

> We also have:
>
> $$\int{d^3xe^{-i\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}} = V\delta_{\boldsymbol{p},0}$$

Now, I've tried to interpret the left-hand side of this equation as the Fourier transform of the constant function 1, but my understanding is that would give something like $2\pi\delta(\boldsymbol{p})$ - at least in one dimension, so the multiplication by the volume is baffling me. Can anyone help here?

Comment: You have a finite volume, so it gives a Kronecker delta; note also that $p$ takes discrete values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quantizing inside a box of volume $V$. Therefore in this context, $$\int d^3x \neq \int_{\textrm{all space}}d^3x = \infty\,.$$
Instead,
$$\int d^3x = \int_{\textrm{box of volume } V}d^3x = V\,.$$
Then, if $\vec{p}\neq0$,
$$
\int d^3x\, e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} = 0\,,
$$
because, intuitively, the oscillations of $e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}$ "cancel out" when added up over the entire box. Really, $\vec{p}$ takes on discrete values for which this integral is zero, except when $\vec{p}=0$. (This is an orthogonality condition, with the constant function 1 being orthogonal to the $e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}$'s.) So, we have a discrete set of $\vec{p}$'s and an integral that takes on a *finite* value if $\vec{p}=0$ and is zero for other values of $\vec{p}$. This is the very definition of
$$
\int d^3x\, e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} = V\delta_{\vec{p},\vec{0}}\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much, that's the kind of insight I was looking for. For some reason my brain completely overlooked the effect of the discreteness of p, and the very moment I read your answer I had that "haha" moment that made everything clear :-). Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @march. Perhaps you can also help with this other equation that appears in the same box: $\frac 1 V\sum_{\vec{p}} e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} = \delta^3(\vec{x})$. I've tried to apply the same kind of logic you suggested in your answer, but without success